# SignatureDoesNotMatch error while amazon web service SES through HTTP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am stuck at SignatureDoesNotMatch error while using aws ses. I am creating signature key by using GMT DATE and security key with HMAC SHA256 and then converting it to Base64.

Signature = base64(HMAC SHA256(Date,Security KEY));

Url: https://email.us-west-2.amazonaws.com?Action=SendEmail&Source=exmaple%40gmail.com&Destination.ToAddresses.member.1=person2%40gmail.com&Message.Subject.Data=Hey&Message.Body.Text.Data=Hello

And input headers as x-amz-date: Thu, 30 Jul 2015 18:15:51 +0000

X-Amzn-Authorization: AWS3-HTTPS AWSAccessKeyId=AccessKEY,Algorithm=HmacSHA256,Signature=sign calculated using DATE and security Key.

Please tell me if i am calculating signature in wrong way or anything else is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem with a different service the other day and the solution was my parameters were not alphabetically ordered. You should try switching the "Message.Subject.Data" order with the "Message.Body.Text.Data" as the latter should appear earlier lexicographically. This should fix your problem.

Comment: Just Tried..no luck..:(